# How to check web api token is valid or not in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on Angularjs Authentication and I am getting tokens from web API, in routechange event I want to check the generated token is valid or not, if it is valid then i want to redirect to some other route, if the token is not valid then i want to redirect to login page.

How to check the token is valid or not

Answer (score 1):

I think you wil need to look at  `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(){});`

to validate your token;